# chartjs data isn't passing to django webpage

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I'm trying to build a webpage with a chart in it. For the chart i'm using Chartjs.
Hardcoded data is no problem for the Chartjs chart. But if I'm trying to pass dynamic data the chart doesn't render.

The labels and results output is 46 (the dataframe is 46 rows with 1 column)

**View.py**

```
def results(request):
    return render(request, 'results.html')

def result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
                data = request.FILES['file']
                # handle_uploaded_file(data)
                data = pd.read_csv(data,header=0, sep=',')
                df = data.values
                df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.reshape(-1,len(data.columns)))
                x = getPredictions(df2)
                x = np.array(x)
                result = x.reshape(-1,1).round()
                df = pd.DataFrame(data=result, columns=['output'])
                labels = len(df)
                # result = list(result)
                return render(request, 'results.html', {'result': result, 'labels': labels})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

**html page**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <div class="card card-tasks">
                            <h4>Chart.</h4>
                            <canvas id="line-chart" width="500" height="350"></canvas>
                              <script>
                                new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
                                  type: 'line',
                                  data: {
                                    labels: {labels|safe},
                                    datasets: [{
                                        data: {result|safe},
                                        label: "output chart",
                                        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                        fill: false
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  options: {
                                    title: {
                                      display: true,
                                      text: 'output chart'
                                    }
                                  }
                                });
                              </script>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>



{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the variables to show up, in your template, you have to wrap them inside two curly braces: `{{ }}`, you are using only one.

Modify your chart code as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <div class="card card-tasks">
                            <h4>Chart.</h4>
                            <canvas id="line-chart" width="500" height="350"></canvas>
                              <script>
                                new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
                                  type: 'line',
                                  data: {
                                    labels: {{ labels |safe }},
                                    datasets: [{
                                        data: {{ result|safe }},
                                        label: "output chart",
                                        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                                        fill: false
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  options: {
                                    title: {
                                      display: true,
                                      text: 'output chart'
                                    }
                                  }
                                });
                              </script>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>



{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I've added the ```{{  }}``` with ```{{ |safe }}``` but that didn't work

Comment: When you make a post request, have you verified if `result` and `labels`  variables actually contain data? And have tried rendering without filtering them through ` | safe`?

Comment: I've added the {{ result }} and {{ labels }} in a different div container. (so outside the chart). the result and labels are showing data. both of them got 46 rows of data. So the data is the same in lenght. (I've ruled that out)

Comment: I think I got it. In your chat, put your template variables inside quotations: `"{{ result }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Amir for helping with the sugestion.

1. I had to update the scripts from chartjs. that made it work
2. had to put `"{}"` around the data and labels